# magento2.4.6 can't load css and js (layout) after installation on windows 10

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

I'm very confusing what's the matter?
I use :

> xampp3.3
> php 8.2
> magento 2.4.6
> elasticsearch 8.8.1

I did all the others said in forums and other questions in stackoverflow or magento stackexchange. but my problem didn't resolve.

[image]

what I did:

1. setting in the database core_config_data  table:

> INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value)  VALUES ('dev/static/sign',0)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;

and set 'web/seo/use_rewrites' to 0 due to an answer in forums.

2. remove folders in 'pub\static'  and 'var'.
3. change owner and give permissions:

> takeown /f . /r

this commands one by one:

```
icacls .\pub /grant Everyone:F /t
icacls .\var /grant Everyone:F /t
icacls .\app\etc /grant Everyone:F /t
```

4. on httpd.conf the line below is active: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
5. add this section to httpd.conf:

> <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2"> Options Indexes
> SymLinksifOwnerMatch MultiViews AllowOverride All Require all granted

and

> timeout 300

6. in di.xml, change developerMaterialization value from symLink to Copy.
7. run this commands one by one

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento cache:flush
8. delete cache folder under var and even clean cashe by:

   php bin\magento cache:clean
   php bin\magento cache:flush

I use localhost, and also use 127.0.0.1 in store url and admin url.
magento2 is loaded but without any css. and the admin panel not loaded at all (404 error).
I test on developer and also production mode.

my installation command for magento 2.4.6 is :

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento2/  --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=root --db-password=root  --admin-firstname=E --admin-lastname=R --admin-email=some@gmail.com  --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US  --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch8 --use-sample-data --cleanup-database
```

I spent much time but without any success.

Comment: Do the files exist under their requested location? Are you sure this is a Composer problem after all?

Comment: yes I checked, files is there. what do you mean about your second question? composer problem?

Comment: I try to magento2.4.6.p1 . and did all from the first. it worked fine. I don't know. but worked. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reason for this, first at all, you need to open the 404 link in browser to see the actual issue, sometime It's the issue with permission (need to check the Apache/Nginx log)

Second, reason likely to happen because files did not generate properly, for this case, you need to enable the `developer` mode

See here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html#change-to-developer-mode

Then run command `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Hope this work for you.

Comment: thanks, but not worked :( .